# What is the difference between "to bring "and "bringing"

Tags: verb-forms

I have this question from a TOEFL iBT test :

> The flexibility of film allows the artist ***_*___** unbridled imagination to the animation of cartoon characters.

with these 4 choices:

> (A)    to bring
>   (B) bringing
>   (C) is brought
>   (D) brings

I am pretty sure that the answer is either `to bring` or `bringing`, I now both of them is correct, but what is the better ? and how to know that? I mean why there is one of them is better than the other ?

Comment: Actually, only *to bring* is correct.  You could use "bringing" if the object-phrase for *allow* did not have a specific actor in it:  *... allows bringing unbridled imagination...*.  I'll have to let someone else go into the reasoning behind that, though.

Comment: @Hellion Put it as a reply! They'll edit/supplement it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case, *allow* is used as "allow somebody to do something"; *to bring* is the correct answer.
You could also use *allow* as "allow something"; in that case, you could use a gerund, as in "We don't allow smoking."

The difference is that in the first case the direct object is the person who is allowed to do something; in the second case, the direct object is the action that is allowed.

Comment: kiam, interesting observation; to some extent one can generalize this rule, though. For example: "We don't run across smoking", but Jane Austin would have said "We don't run across to smoke". Am I getting confused?

Comment: As phrasal verb, _run across_ is used as "run across somebody" or "run across something"; in that case, I would say that "run across to smoke" is not possible. "Run across" could also mean "run from a side to the other side," and in that case "run across to smoke" would mean "run from one side to the other side with the purpose of going to smoke."